# Add an "Undo" button or "Are you sure you want to approve" to Suggested Edits (2k+ rep users)

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, moderator-abilities

Today I saw a very bad edit and was determined to reject it, but mistakenly pressed the "Approve" button. I know it requers 3 different people to accept and edit, but if there was another one like me or someone that approved the edit although it's bad, my vote will be the one that counts. I also think that this is a good practice so people will give a second thought before approving and won't do this too automatically.

[image]

Another proposal will be (in order to not put "roadblocks"), is that we will have the option to reverse approval in the next 10 seconds or so. This way, if one pressed "Approve" by mistake, he will have the option to reverse it (something like "undo" button in Gmail when you send an email).

[image]

P.S.
I know there are automatic tests made by the system, but it still didn't prevent me pressing the "Approve" button by mistake

Comment: Putting roadblocks in the review queues discourages people from participating

Comment: @just.another.programmer It's just adding "Yes"/"No" question, I don't think it will discourage someone, but this is why I proposing it so people will say their opinion

Comment: I don't think this would make any difference, but @just.another.programmer less participation from people would can't be bothered to hit Y/N in the suggested edit queue would undoubtedly be beneficial. Of 100 incorrect approvals, 1 is probably a misclick, 99 are just people who don't care.

Comment: In the last days I had a few questions where I was about to reject the edit, I found then that 1 or 2 people already rejected the edit too, but then suddenly I got the message that someone had already approved it in the meantime. How can one approval outweight 2 or 3 rejects? People reject for a reason!

Comment: @JensG, that could only happen if the OP approved it or if someone chose "improve" and marked it as helpful. Usually though it's that it was sat at 2 approves and 2 rejects, so its a race between you and the next robo approver.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Yeay, Undo would be great.

Comment: You always can go back a few minutes later and rollback to the last version.

Comment: That question is as useless as "Do you want to quit?" when closing a desktop application, where the application has no pending changes. It's annoying. Yes, I want to exit, that's why I clicked the X in the first place. Don't encourage misclicking.

Comment: @CodeCaster, there is a reason they added that question there. Also, if you don't want that question we can try the "undo" button. And, as mentioned, you can sometimes click by mistake. It actually saved me many times when I accidentally closed different programs

Comment: The gmail-style undo could be done as a user script i suppose... Might be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

No, a second prompt should not be needed or added.

Something like 99.9% of the time, you will click on the correct action button. In those cases you have added a second click which adds no value. Especially as a "reject" can be equally damaging, so you'd need to prompt the user "are you sure you want to reject?" as well.

In the rare case when you realize you made a mistake, you can just go into the review history and go back to the post through there. If the edit has gone through, roll it back. If it hasn't and you feel strongly enough about it, keep an eye on the review item and if it ends up being approved, roll back.

Remember to **optimize for success, not for failure.**

Comment: Another issue is that you'd need to support the same for audits and delay posting a pass/fail message until the _next_ edit has been handled. This would get _very_ confusing.